# Referencing a cell as the Value to use in an IFS statement in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, ifs

I'm using an `IFS` statement to decide what a cell should use as a value dependant on what is entered into the cell.
Which is fine, except that I have to hard code it into every cell that uses it as an equation.
I need to have the Value1, Value2 etc be whatever is in another cell. That way I can update one cell and have it cascade.

```
=IFS(C34=<100, "$10", C34=500, "$5", C34=1000, "$2")
```

I need the "$10" to be a value of another cell, ie B28

I've tried `!B28`, `$B28`, `=(B28)` and every other thing I could think of. I can't find anything online in Google's documentation.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: as far as i know google sheets doesn't support `=<`operand you need to use `<=`

Comment: Fair enough Mohammad.

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ODOSSh-xSQbM37t_6XXCsX3LS5RnPdd4c2bVK4dANHo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @player0 Sorry. It is public now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IFS(B1<=100, "$15.75", B1<=1000, "$8.41")
```

[image: ,]

---

```
=IFS(B1<=100, D1, B1<=1000, "$8.41")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you! I could have sworn that was the first thing I tried and it kept giving me an error... But it works now, so I probably had a syntax problem that I was just not seeing.